# Getting error 0004: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, asp.net-webpages

I am working on a ASP.NET Web Pages site with SQL Server CE 4.0.

I believe my SQL Server CE 4.0 database is working fine. I can connect to it without any problems on my dev machine with and without Entity Framework.

Once I push the site to the server, I can connect to it fine without entity framework using this connection string:

```
<add name="StarterSite" 
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

My Entity Framework connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="StarterSiteEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.ProductModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.ProductModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.ProductModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.sdf&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I try to make any EF database calls I get this error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Schema specified is not valid.
>
> Errors:
>   App_Code.ProductModel.ssdl(2,88) : error 0004: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid.
>
> Errors:
>   App_Code.ProductModel.ssdl(2,88) : error 0004: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 23:         using (var db = new StarterSiteEntities())
>   Line 24:         {
>   Line 25:             product = (from p in db.Products
>   Line 26:                          where p.ProductID ==  productId
>   Line 27:                          select p).FirstOrDefault();
>
> Source File: c:\sites\www.foosite.org\Admin-RUF\Admin-Product-Edit.cshtml    Line: 25

Stack Trace:

[MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
App_Code.ProductModel.ssdl(2,88) : error 0004: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact. ]
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() +8610213
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) +189
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +182
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths) +244
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader) +90
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollectionLoader.LoadItemCollection(StoreMetadataEntry entry) +16
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection(IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry) +163
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken) +191
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader) +246
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections) +586
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure) +75
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +150
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +75
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +36
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +152
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +133
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +87
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +251
   ASP._Page_admin_ruf_Admin_Product_Edit_cshtml.Execute() in c:\sites\www.foosite.org\Admin-RUF\Admin-Product-Edit.cshtml:25
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +69
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +131
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +116

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try going to your SQL Tab at VS and copy&paste the Connection String.

Comment: Deploy System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll with your app

Comment: @ErikEJ Thx for responding. Where do I find System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll to deploy it? It's not in my bin folder.

Comment: It is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop\System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity on my PC

Comment: For whatever reason, no matter how many times I read that error message, all I ever saw was "System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll", which was in my bin folder. Teaches me to slow down, or just step away for a long while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll with your app, It is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop\System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity on my PC.