# Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

So I've been trying for days without success to try and resolve this error.

> Error 4: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall
>   SQL Server Compact.

I have googled for answers but to no avail.

I have the dll included in my Components folder and the application seems to know it's there, but just won't load it.

Any suggestions would be great.

EDIT: Should have been in a little clearer... I have re installed as the error suggested.

I have run time versions 3.5 SP2 x86, 3.5 SP2 x64 and 4.0 SP1 x64 installed, I am targeting the 3.5 SP2.

I added to the dll to my Components folder to see if it would solve things, however it makes no difference to the error.

Comment: *Reinstall SQL Server Compact.* Did you do what it said?

Comment: Did you also deploy SQLCE run-time in your production machine? It's not just a single DLL...

Comment: Did you Reinstall SQL Server Compact? Have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216205/getting-error-0004-could-not-load-system-data-sqlserverce-entity-dll-reinstall) answer.